# No matter what I do, Apache2 is using the event MPM. Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to completely remove Apache2, reboot and then using this command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork
```

Still, Apache2 will work only in event MPM:

```
root@ubuntu-vm:~# apachectl -V | grep -i mpm
Server MPM:     event
```

I need it to work with prefork, can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you show what `apache2 -l`  lists?

Answer (score 2):

`apachectl -v` only shows the default compiled MPM, not what is actually running. Enable `mod_info` and check the output under "Sever Settings" for "MPM Name"

Answer (score 0):

What do you get from this command?

ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm*

You need to enable the mpm module you want to use with the command a2enmod.